# Unexpected Infinite for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I am beginner in C and I was experimenting with `for` loop and I came across a infinite loop which should not be a infinite loop,  can anyone help me understand why it is a infinite loop

```
void main()
{
    int i;

    for(i=1,printf("Initialization");i++ <=5,printf("\nCondition");printf("%d",i))

    printf("\nInside the loop :");
}
```

while this is not a infinite loop

```
void main()
{
    int i;

    for(i=1,printf("Intialization");printf("\nCondition"),i++<= 5;printf("%d",i))

    printf("\nInside the loop\n");
}
```

Comment: because the return value of `printf` is never 0 in that case? (and since you put it second in the condition, that is what is being compared)

Comment: What possessed you write code like that?

Comment: I was just trying different things with for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that your loop conditions (between two semicolons) look like this:

```
i++ <=5, printf("\nCondition") // First loop
printf("\nCondition"), i++<= 5 // Second loop
```

Both conditions are *comma expressions*, meaning that only the last part matters in terms of generating the value (both parts are good for their side effects, though).

In the first case, the overall condition result is what `printf("\nCondition")` returns. It always returns non-zero<sup>*</sup>, interpreted as "true", so the loop is infinite.

In the second case, the overall result is what `i++<=5` returns, which starts off as "true", and becomes "false" after five iterations. That is when the second loop terminates.

<sup>*</sup> Specifically, `printf` returns the number of characters printed, so in your case that would be 10. This is not essential to understanding why the loop is infinite, though.

Comment: Check the return value of printf("") please and rethink your non-zero.

Comment: @NiclasM Please kindly point out where do you see `printf("")` in OP's code. I mean, OP has only one `printf` in that condition; it prints `"\nCondition"`, and always returns ten, a non-zero value.

Comment: Nowhere. You still clearly state that "It [printf] always returns non-zero".

Comment: @NiclasM Yes, that's right - "it" (`printf` from the first condition) returns ten, because its argument is ten-characters long.

Comment: `printf()` returns a negative value on error. Even if OP redirected `stdout` to a file, the loop wouldn't end when the hard drive was full.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 conditions remember that printf returns number of characters printed and that is always non zero hence results in infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Simple comma operator realizes all side effects in operands, discards result of it's first operand, and then evaluates it's second one. So, in first snippet, althought i++ will be realized, condition <= result will be discarted, so effective condition in for will be result of printf("\nCondition"), that's 10=true. In second snippet first operand result printf(...) = 10 will be discard, and will be used as pure condition just i<=5.

Here some doc :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator,

https://uvesway.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/c-loops-for-and-the-comma-operator/

Answer (score 0):

If we write more than one condition in for loop condition portion compiler will check all conditions but it will consider the right most condition to check whether the condition is TRUE/FALSE.

In your first program you write two conditions one is i++<5,printf("\ncondition").
printf always return number of printable characters in that function.so every time printf returning 9 in your program for that only condition never become false.

But in your second program you write i++<5 is right most condition for that when ever i value becomes 5 condition becomes false so control will come out side of the loop.
If you want to check whether printf returning number of printable characters then try this.
    enter code here

> unsigned int a=printf("HAI");

in this case printf will return 3 to the integer variable a